# Failed to determine BusFactory implementation class name.: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory

Tags: java, soap, jboss

I tried everything to avoid JBoss cxf from loaded with the following configuration in jboss-deployment-structure.xml.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>  
    <deployment>  
         <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="webservices" /> 
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment> 
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

My code fails at this part:It is not a maven project, all the jars are under lib folder and dynamic web project.I used the above configuration to tell JBoss to use my Jars but looks like still using JBoss jars looks like.I also have am using JBossEAP7 and cxf2.1.3 jar under my lib folder in eclipse. Any idea?

```
    SOAPConnection soapConnection = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();
    SOAPMessage response = soapConnection.call(request, endpointUrl);


19:17:56,103 SEVERE [org.apache.cxf.BusFactory] (default task-2) Failed to determine BusFactory implementation class name.: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getBusFactoryClass(BusFactory.java:390)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.newInstance(BusFactory.java:316)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.newInstance(BusFactory.java:303)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.saaj.SOAPConnectionImpl.getConduitInitiator(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:206)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.saaj.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:69)
    at com.minico.webservices.quoterate.C1ServiceUtil.sendSoapRequest(C1ServiceUtil.java:102)
    at com.minico.webservices.quoterate.C1ServiceUtil.getQuoteNumber(C1ServiceUtil.java:63)
    at com.minico.webservices.quoterate.C1ServiceUtil.getQuote(C1ServiceUtil.java:154)
    at com.minico.webservices.quoterate.IQuoteRateServiceImpl.getQuoteRate(IQuoteRateServiceImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:136)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:82)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:54)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:220)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:78)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:92)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:285)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:168)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:175)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.doPost(AbstractCXFServlet.java:153)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:792)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19:17:56,122 ERROR [com.ServiceUtil] (default task-2) JBWS024009: No ConduitInitiator is available for https://xxxx

19:17:56,125 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.saaj.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:69)
```

Comment: upload the server.log issue

Comment: Thanks@FranciscoMelojunior I have added the log. I still working on it and no luck.

Comment: This happens only when using exclude-subsystems? Our reproducers here are showing:  No ConduitInitiator. That's weird.

Comment: Without exclude-subsystem event he server doesn't start at all. It complains about CXF jar and to use JBoss jar.

Comment: Send a reproducer then, we would like to test it then.

Comment: What is reproducer mean?

Comment: It's an application that triggers the issue.